# Eloquent with query on relations with nested WHERE

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-6

I'm struggling with Eloquent with query on relation.

For example, I'm looking for only the client John who doesn't have transaction.

How can I do this with Eloquent?

Client model relation

```php
public function transactions()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Transaction::class);
}
```

```php
$results = Client::whereDoesntHave('transactions', function ($query) use ($inputFirst, $period) {
    $query->where('transactions.period_id', '=', $period->id)
          ->where('firstname', '=', $inputFirst);
    })
    ->orderBy('id', 'desc')
    ->get();
```

A little help would be great.
Thanks

Comment: your query looks correct, so what is your problem?

Comment: If I understood your question correctly, you want clients who don't have transactions with clients named John? Then you need to use the operator <> instead of =. So your where should be something where('firstname, '<>', $inputFirst); Sorry if that's not what you're asking...

Comment: Your question is still confusing can you please elaborate and also add model definitions

Comment: Client model relation `public function transactions()     {         return $this->hasMany(Transaction::class);     }`Sorry for the confusion. I'm looking for only the client John who doesn't have transaction. Now, Eloquent give me all transactions

Comment: like @adolfotcar said change your where clause to '<>' instead of '='

Comment: well, then you shouldn't be nesting inside the whereDoesntHave() funcion. Just leave the where outside, more or less like this: Client::whereDoesntHave('transactions')->where('firstname', $inputFirst)->get(). Laravel creates the statement: select * from clientswhere not exists (SECOND SELECT), the way you're doing the where is going inside the SECOND SELECT....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue with your code is that you are nesting the statements. The way you are doing Laravel is generating a SQL like this:

```
select * from `clients` where not exists 
(select * from `transactions` 
where `clients`.`id` = `transactions`.`client_id` 
and `name` = John)
```

But the actual SQL code you're looking for is:

```
select * from `clients` where not exists 
(select * from `transactions` 
where `clients`.`id` = `transactions`.`client_id`) 
and `name` = John)
```

For that your code should be:

```
$results = Client::whereDoesntHave('transactions')
                   ->where('firstname', '=', $inputFirst)
                   ->orderBy('id', 'desc')
                   ->get();
```

*I didn't include the transactions.period_id, coz I wasn't sure if where you're looking to have it. But if it's meant to be inside the second select, leave in the nested statement, if not leave outside.